# "cd.." command is not working ? how to fix it?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

"cd.." command is  not working ?

```
C:\Users\Abhishek Gunjan>cd..
```

it says

```
'cd..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try with a space in between cd and the dots? What OS?

Answer (score 4):

you missing space you should write

```
cd ..
```

Comment: Wrong. `cd..` works. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

try to type an space between the cd command and the folder you want to change to
Be aware that `..` is like a shortcut representing the parent folder
Older versions of DOS/Windows support `cd..` (without space) but that is not the 'standar' way

```
cd ..
```

Comment: `cd..` works for me on the latest 1709.